# Не могу понять почему мой алгоритм не до конца идёт

Tags: python

Есть код на питоне и он не считает оставшиеся элементы. При `graph = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]` он выдаёт:

```
Clique found: [1, 4]
Clique found: [1, 5]
Clique found: [1, 6]
Clique found: [2, 4]
Clique found: [2, 5]
Clique found: [2, 6]
```

А должен:

```
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[1, 6]
[2, 4]
[2, 5]
[2, 6]
[3, 4]
[3, 5]
[3, 6]
```

Не знаю почему, но он не исследует 3 вершину

```py
def clique(N, D, Z, graph):
    if not any((N, D)):
        file_S = []
        for i in range(len(S)):
            file_S.append(S[i]+1)
        print('Clique found: ' + str(file_S))
    elif N:
        x = N[0]
        View(N, D, x, graph)
        if x in Z:
            Z.remove(x)
        Adj_list = Adj(x, graph)
        for i in range(len(Adj_list)):
            if not any((Z, Adj_list)):
                Z.remove(Adj_list[i])
        while Z:
            v = Z[0]
            View(N, D, v, graph)
            if v in Z:
                Z = Z.remove(v)

def View(N, D, v, graph):
    if v in N:
        N.remove(v)
    S.append(v)
    N_v = Adj(v, graph)
    D_v = Adj(v, graph)
    N_adj = list(set(N) & set(N_v))
    D_adj = list(set(D) & set(D_v))
    clique(N_adj, D_adj, N_adj, graph)
    S.remove(v)
    D.append(v)

def Adj(v, X):
    return [i for i, n_v in enumerate(X[v]) if n_v]

#graph = [[0,1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
graph = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]


X = []
for i in range(len(graph)):
    X.append(i)

S = []
N = X.copy()
D = []
Z = X.copy()
clique(N, D, Z, graph)
```